# How to make Coke Material in blender

Tags: materials

I'm doing a fluid simulation of a what's supposed to look like coca cola ( like the ones you see in the commercials )
and I want to know what are the Materials and colors I should use to get that distinctive coca cola look .
if anyone has tried it before and could be of any help 
I'd be really grateful thanks

PS : I'm using cycles render .
.
.
this is an edit to my Question

soo I accidentally had this look a couple of days ago , and I want to get back to it [image: previous look]

this is what it looks like now

[image: recent look]

Comment: cegaton I have used glass material with volume absorption but it looked waay too thick almost like wine , so I added a transparent shader to the first one 
but now I'm still struggling to get the colors right

Comment: Most photos and commercials you see are done with watered down cola, so it is not as dense. A trick to light liquids (and translucent objects) is by placing a bright object behind them so that the liquid stands out  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOdIu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Fluids I often use Volume Absorption in combination with a glass Shader. For cola you can add some bubbles using the particle system to create that bruise effect.

You can change the density for a more darker or lighter look.

[image]

Color used in example: #C37F17

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how your looks so I dont know if mine is more what you are looking for, but this is how I would set it up.

[image]
[image]

Use the principled shader with transmission all the way up (for glass).

I used a mix RGB with a noise factor to break up the color a little bit.

I used an emission shader for the volume with a noise texture (to get those light color swirls). I tried using a volume scatter/absorbtion but I wasn't liking the look it gave me plus the render times shot way up (so the emission shader worked for me).

[image]

Then I just added a particle system for the bubbles, and I threw in some ***Ice Cubes***.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question 
I added photos please check it out 
thanks

Comment: Well I think the problem you have is your lighting. Because you have it right up against the corner of a wall it is going to be tricky to get the correct lighting. If possible I would use an HDRI for the nice reflections and refraction. You need your material to reflect your scene. If you used my node set up I would just focus on the lighting. Professional product photographers spend hours on just the lighting alone.