# How to make a realistic Pepsi material?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm trying to make a realistic material of pepsi. I want it to look like this:
[image]

Without the ice cubes of course. I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109327/how-to-make-coke-material-in-blender), but it doesn't look very good. It is also going to be a fluid simulation.

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 6):

What I landed on was similar to boots, but using a *Clearcoat*.

[image]

I couldn't shade smooth here, I'm assuming you can at some later point in the process.

As far as the fluid sim portion, to me the main thing to aim for is pronounced and persistent bubbles.  I don't know if that can be fully achieved with these controls:

[image]

I think in the longer term an emitter/rigidbody system of some sort would be necessary to maintain the appearance.

All I can say is good luck, because baking these sims to test behavior is very time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

Use a glass shader and set the color with volume absorption.

[image]

read:

[fluid in a glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass/35741#35741)

Answer (score 3):

If you ever want to do it in Eevee, as volumetric are not as good as in Cycles for the moment, you can cheat, essentially with a *Layer Weight* as factor in a *Mix Shader* between the *Principled BSDF* and a *Transparent* node. Give the *Principled BSDF* a *Transmission* of 1. It's not accurate but it can give the illusion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this could be improved a bit by setting the correct index of refraction for the transmission (about 1.3 or slightly higher because of the sugar). You can currently see that the transmitted light is not refracted.

Comment: I've tried but it tdidn't look good, if you've found a good setup I'm interested though, please give your own answer